# Convert node URL to absolute

Tags: theming, hooks, uri

We are using Drupal Core v8.6.2 and we have a `url` variable in our `node--page.html.twig` template. While using `ksm()` and `{{ kint() }}` we are finding that if we use `hook_preproces_node($variables)` that the `url` is inserted into the `$variables` array. Unfortunately this `url` is `relative`, but we need an `absolute` URL in our `twig` template.

How can we convert this `url` variable from our `node--page.html.twig` template to be absolute?

**`node--page.html.twig`**

I have reduced the comments section to only include comments that were relevant to the question.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a node.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - node: The node entity with limited access to object properties and methods.
 * - label: The title of the node.
 * - content: All node items. Use {{ content }} to print them all,
 * - url: Direct URL of the current node.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 * @see template_preprocess_node()
 *
 */
#}

<a href="{{ url }}> {# url is the variable we want to be absolute #}
  <h2> {{ label }} </h2>
  {{ content.body }}
</a>
```

Comment: How are you creating this variable?

Comment: @Kevin I added more lines from the comment's section of the twig template in the question. It is a copy of the `node.html.twig` from the [classy node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21classy%21templates%21content%21node.html.twig/8.6.x) template. So nothing I generated myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hook_preprocess_node` to passe `base_url` to your twig like the following:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  global $base_url;
  $variables['base_url'] = $base_url;
}
```

in `node--page.html.twig` you will get the absolute `url` by:

```
{{ base_url ~ url }}
```